# Trying To Use Javascript To Stop My Form From Submitting Itself When An Email Address That Has Been Used By A Previous User Is Provided

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I want to add a javascript that checks and prevents my form from submitting itself whenever an email address that has been used by someone else is provided by another user.
I know this is not a professional way to do this but I need this solution for a simple project.

Below is the javascript that I have tried myself but not working.

```js
function check(form) /*function to check used email addresses*/ {
    /*the following code checkes whether the entered email address is used*/
if (form.usercheck1.value == "sttf@gmail.com" 
|| form.usercheck1.value == "dandy@gmail.com") 
{
alert("The email address you provided has been used by another user."));
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

```html
<form action='' method='POST' onsubmit="return check_usercheck1();"></form>

<input name='email' id="usercheck1" placeholder='email' required='' type='email'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has various errors.

1. `check_usercheck1` function doesn't exist.
2. Input is in outside of form.
3. Your alert is closed 2 times with 2 `)`, this give a error.
4. Yor code can be refactor.

Check the snippet below.

```js
function check(form) {
    let emails = ['sttf@gmail.com', 'dandy@gmail.com'];
    if (emails.includes(form)) {
        alert("The email address you provided has been used by another user.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function even (e) {
  const formInp = document.getElementById("usercheck1");
  const success = check(formInp.value);
  
  if(!success) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}

window.onload = (event) => {

document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", even);

}
```

```html
<form action='' method='POST' id="form">
  <input name='email' id="usercheck1" placeholder='email' required='' type='email'/>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I appreciate this solution but it didn't work.

Comment: @AyodejiAkingbe why not?

Comment: I don't know...See for yourself @ https://testetstetets.blogspot.com/p/test.html

Comment: @AyodejiAkingbe try again, i've edited.

Comment: still did not work.

Comment: @AyodejiAkingbe blogspot isn't registering events.